# Impossible search algorithm interview question

Tags: algorithm, search

How would you solve this question?

You start with a box containing a quantity x of red marbles, y of green
marbles and z blue marbles, as well as an unlimited supply of red, green
and blue marbles outside the box. One move consists of choosing two
different colours, removing two marbles from the box (one of each of
your two chosen colours), and then adding a marble of the third colour
to the box from your supply. For example, if you choose the colours red
and green, then you remove a red and a green marble, and put back
a blue one. For what starting conditions (expressed as constraints on
x, y, z) can you get exactly one marble in the box by performing zero
or more moves?

Comment: I could provide a dynamic programming solution with O(X*Y*Z) complexity as a starting point

Comment: Start with the simple cases and look for the pattern. 1 marble works. 2 marbles work if they're different colors, and fail if they're the same color. 3 marbles work with {2,1,0}, but fail with {3,0,0} or {1,1,1}.

Comment: @גלעדברקן you are right, i have misread the question.

Answer (score 3):

It will converge to one if:

1) Out of three (x, y, z) only two of them are even or odd. 
i.e. All three of them can't be even or odd, one has to be different.

Any of them can be even or odd there is no constraint on color.

**Edit:**
As pointed out by [@onelyner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11641278/one-lyner) initially, (3, 0, 0) won't work despite following the first rule. Generalizing,

2) Any two of the (x, y, z) can't be zero initially if third **is NOT EQUAL to** one.

i.e. it must not look like (0, 0, n) where n is not equal to 1.

Something to note here is that we can reach (3, 0, 0) from (2, 1, 1), which should converge to one because it follows both the rules. And if done properly, it surely does converge to one

(2, 1, 1) -> (1, 2, 0) -> (0, 1, 1) -> (1, 0, 0)

Comment: How do you do for (3,0,0) ?

Comment: @גלעדברקן True! I missed that case. Initially, two out of 3 also can't be zero. Edited answer

Comment: @OneLyner +1 for the border case! Edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Can you please explain the reason for the odd/even constraint?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Bear with my bad English,to reach (0,1,0), we MUST have (1,0,1) (odd[O] and even[E] have switched states), to reach here we can have (0,1,2) or (2,1,0) again, O and E had switched states. We can start from anywhere (2O,1E) or (1O, 2E) but ultimately be in another form after one step. You'll also observe, (x, 1, 0) will always converge if done properly (more general case where 1 and 0 switch at each step and x reduces by 1). This is why to reach a state with 2E,1O (0,0,1) we need above constraint. Otherwise we'll always have either 3E,0O or 0E,3O and it will never converge.

Comment: @Dave I don't quite understand what your example is. (1,1,1) cannot reduce to (0,0,0). It will converge to (0,0,2) only.

Answer (score 1):

To explain the parity issue TotallyNoob [revealed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58267744/2034787), we can think about the state as a partition of a sum into three parts. At each stage, the sum is reduced by 1 (-2 + 1), which means the parity of the sum flips. For an odd number, there would be two ways to represent it as a sum of three (odd + odd + odd) or (even + even + odd), and for an even number there would also be two ways, (odd + odd + even) or (even + even + even).

We also know that at each step, all three of the parts flip parity since two are decremented and one incremented. So either we're going between (odd, odd, odd) and (even, even, even) or we're moving between (odd, odd, even) and (even, even, odd). Since we know that the final state is (even, even, odd), we know the state changes must be between (odd, odd, even) and (even, even, odd).

But is this sufficient to know that any starting values (except the obvious `{x, 0, 0}, x > 1`) would work?

Comment: Proof by induction should be able to show that the parity method is sufficient, provided that one avoids transforming (x,1,1) to (x+1,0,0).

Answer (score 0):

Working backwards...

From {0,0,1} we can get to {0,1,k} for any k >= 0 by repeatedly picking the 1 to decrement.

From {0,1,k}, k>=1, we can get to {2x,1,k) by alternating between the k and the 1 to decrement.

From {2x,1,k}, k>=1, we can get to {2x,2y+1,k) by alternating between the 2x and the k to decrement.

Thus, any trio which has at least one even, at least one odd, and at least 2 above zero is reachable from a single marble in the inverse.

Comment: Note that I'm ignoring which specific color ends up at each value here since it doesn't matter.